# PHP my form wont set submit

Tags: php, forms, submit

I'm a beginner in `php`, and I wanted to do some form that hide after you press submit button and tell you value of input, but it doesn't work. I think there is some problem with my submit button ( i spend like 2 hours trying to solve this problem). Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jednoduchý formulář</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $show = True;
  if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    if(empty($_GET['jmeno'])){echo "Vyplnte jmeno";}else {
      if (empty($_GET['prijmeni'])){echo "Vyplnte prijmeni";}else{

    echo "Jméno: ".$_GET['jmeno'];
        echo "<br>";
    echo "Prijmeni: ".$_GET['prijmeni'];
        echo "<br>";
    echo "Je Vám ".$_GET['vek'];
        echo "<br>";
    echo "Děkuji za vyplnění formuláře";

    $show=False;
  };
  };
};

  if ($show){ ?>
<form  action="form1.php" method="get" >
<table width="250" align="center">
    <tr>
     <td>Jmeno:</td> <td><input type="text" name="jmeno" value="" size="10" maxlength="25"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Prijmeni:</td> <td><input type="text" name="prijmeni" value="" size="10" maxlength="25"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Heslo:</td> <td><input type="password" name="heslo" value="" size="10" maxlength="15"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Vek</td> <td><input type="radio" name="vek" value="méně než 18 let "checked> mene nez 18  <br>
                     <input type="radio" name="vek" value="18 let a více">  18 a vice  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
    };
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because you have not set the name of Submit input, but you are verifiying that input in PHP to be isset:

Change your code to.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much it is working. That little mistake made so much trouble and you solved it in few second :). Thank you so much.

Comment: It's okay. Mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem. In future try to verify each line of php one by one and you will catch the error easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$_POST()`, beyond that you need to name the submit input, then check if it's set.

```
<?php

IF (isset($_POST['form1'])) {

    $err = "";
    IF (!empty($_POST['jmeno'])) { $jmeno = $_POST'jmeno']; }ELSE{ $err .= "jmeno is empty.<br>"; }
    IF (!empty($_POST['prijmeni'])) { $prijmeni = $_POST'prijmeni']; }ELSE{ $err .= "prijmeni is empty"; }
    IF (!empty($_POST['heslo'])) { $heslo = $_POST'heslo']; }ELSE{ $err .= "heslo is empty"; }
    // ...... etc.

    IF (!empty($err)) {

        $result = "<p>".$err."</p>";
        $result .= "<form action=\"form1.php\" name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" >
<table width=\"250\" align=\"center\">

    <tr>
     <td>Jmeno:</td> <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"jmeno\" value=\"".$_POST['jmeno']."\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"25\"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Prijmeni:</td> <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"prijmeni\" value=\"".$_POST['prijmeni']."\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"25\"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Heslo:</td> <td><input type=\"password\" name=\"heslo\" value=\"".$_POST['heslo']."\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"15\"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Vek</td> <td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"vek\" value=\"méne než 18 let \"checked> mene nez 18  <br>
                     <input type=\"radio\" name=\"vek\" value=\"18 let a více\">  18 a vice  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"form1\" value=\"submit\"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>";

    }ELSE{

        // everything is good to go....
        $result = "whatever the next html body should be.";

    }

}ELSE{

    $result = "<form action=\"form1.php\" name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" >
<table width=\"250\" align=\"center\">

    <tr>
     <td>Jmeno:</td> <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"jmeno\" value=\"\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"25\"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Prijmeni:</td> <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"prijmeni\" value=\"\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"25\"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Heslo:</td> <td><input type=\"password\" name=\"heslo\" value=\"\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"15\"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Vek</td> <td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"vek\" value=\"méne než 18 let \" checked> mene nez 18  <br>
                     <input type=\"radio\" name=\"vek\" value=\"18 let a více\">  18 a vice  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"form1\" value=\"submit\"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>";

}

// display results
echo("<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jednoduchý formulár</title>
</head>
<body>
".$result."
</body>
</html>");

?>
```